# Bitnami Odoo9 Installation : Unknown error while running chown -R root:daemon

Tags: terminal, odoo-9, bitnami

I got the following error when I tried to install bitnami **odoo 9** in my fresh ubuntu system.

Actually, as in AWS server, my default user is **ubuntu**

```
Please wait while Setup installs Bitnami Odoo Stack on your computer.

 Installing
 0% ______________ 50% ______________ 100%
 ########################################Warning: Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete 
correctly
 Unknown error while running chown -R root:daemon 
/opt/odoo/apps/odoo/bin/openerp-gevent

Press [Enter] to continue:
Warning: Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete 
correctly
 Error creating dynamic link /opt/odoo/apps/odoo/bnconfig 
/opt/odoo/apps/odoo/updateip
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Bitnami developer here. Could you please let us know more information about the issue? It would be helpful if you share the Operating System you're using and its version, the server type you launched and the disk size. It seems that the server doesn't have the required resources to install the application. We also suggest you use the Bitnami Launchpad for AWS that  gives you fully configured applications and development stacks ready to run on your Amazon Web Services account in minutes. https://bitnami.com/aws. Regards. Jota

Comment: I have the same issue - Amazon Lightsail 1GB memory.
Trying to install bitnami-lampstack-7.1.12-0-linux-x64-installer.run